# Wget windows7 batch file turn off logging

Tags: logging, windows-7, batch-file, wget

I try to create a cronjob on windows7 iis. I downloaded the wget.exe from [here](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/), and created a batch file called: "cron.bat"

```
"D:\creation\software developer\wget\wget.exe" -q http://www.webshop.loc/cron;
pause;
```

My problem is whenever I call that file it creates a file called: "cron;#" where # is the number of the file calls. So on first call: "cron;" on second call: "cron;1", on third call: "cron;2" is created. How can I stop this flood of file creations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell wget to write the output to the screen instead of a file, by using `-O -`

You can then pipe it to "nothing" with `>NUL`

Your command will become

```
"D:\creation\software developer\wget\wget.exe" -q http://www.webshop.loc/cron -O - >NUL
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution, I created an executable cron.js file:

```
Http={
    GET: function (url) {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        return xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
};

Http.GET("http://www.webshop.loc/cron/execute");
```